# Command 'which perl' only displays after exit from bash

Tags: bash, shell

Ok, I'm back with another simple question...

Unix flavor: SunOS devsrv2 5.10 Generic_147148-26 i86pc i386 i86pc

In my work environment, I log into a tsch shell...  and after I login, I type "bash" and it drops me into a bash shell (which I prefer).

So instead of always having to type "bash", I created a .cshrc script that has one line in it:

```
#.cshrc
bash
```

and after logging out and logging back in, I go DIRECTLY into a bash shell...

Here's the problem...  Before, when I did the two step process of logging in and then typing "bash", I could type "which perl" and I would get the response "/usr/bin/perl"...

Now I don't get anything back....  UNTIL I issue the command "exit" and then the "/usr/bin/per" text comes up...

so, to summarize:

1. I login
2. I type "bash"
3. I type "which perl"
4. I get back "/usr/bin/per"

when I add the .cshrc file and login:

1. Drops me directly into bash
2. I type "which perl"
3. I don't get anything but the command line back
4. I type "exit"
5. I get "/usr/bin/perl"

I have a feeling it has to do with the system setting STDOUT when I type bash vs when I manually do it in the cshrc file, but I'm not sure how to export it in the script...

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know what are you trying to achieve here, but you could change your login shell instead.  Maybe use `chsh`.

Comment: I'm trying to use a bash shell and bypass having to type "bash"...

Comment: Is `which` implemented as a Csh script on your system? The corresponding Bash command is `type`.

Comment: If you can't change your shell or have your admin change it for you as suggested by @devnull, then perhaps you want your `.cshrc` to say `exec /bin/bash` instead... That will replace your currently running `[t]csh` with `bash`, rather than running `bash` as a child process that gets confused by input buffering, etc....

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to manually change your shell...  There are "behind the scenes" things that you may not be taken into consideration that need to be loaded before you enter the shell...

The best way to do this is to have a root user run the command:

usermod -s /usr/bin/bash userfoo #user: userfoo

This will get your environment set up properly, saving you lots of headache and time.

Comment: You can usually do this yourself with `chsh`, no need for an admin.